# Installing Postgres 9.6 in Cellar

Tags: homebrew

I have postgres 10 installed and I want to switch to Postgres 9.6.

When I run `brew search postgresql` I get the following:

```
==> Searching local taps...
postgresql ✔                                    postgresql@9.6 ✔                              hashrocket/formulas/postgresql_autodoc          postgresql@9.4                                  postgresql@9.5
```

But when I run `brew switch postgresql 9.6` I get:

```
Error: postgresql does not have a version "9.6" in the Cellar.
postgresql installed versions: 10.4
```

Comment: What does `brew info postgresql@9.6`says?

Answer (score 0):

One can switch postgresql version in postgres Application. Install Application via Cask

`brew cask install postgres`

[image: Postgres-Application]

Then add (via plus button) a new server and specify the path to postgres version
(for me the version is under

`ls /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/`)
For more information see postgresapp.com (https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html)

Hope that helps.